# My pc is listening and does not advance, does not show me an error or anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am trying to test the Python Speech Recognition library for speech recognition and go to text, however when I run the program the cursor stays blinking and does not advance, no errors come out, I have to press Ctrl + C to interrupt it

This is my code, is a only example

```
import speech_recognition as sr

   r = sr.Recognizer() 
   mic = sr.Microphone(device_index=0)
   with mic as source:
      print('Di algo: ')
      audio = r.listen(source)

      try:
         text = r.recognize_google(audio, language="es-EC")
         print('Tu dijiste:', text)
      except:
         print('No puedo escucharte')
```

But it does nothing and doesn't even give me an error or return the exception message
stays like this

```
PS C:\Users\dell\Documents\Cuarentena\Pruebas de reconocimiento de voz> & C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe "c:/Users/dell/Documents/Cuarentena/Pruebas de reconocimiento de voz/prueba1.py"
Di algo:
|
```

when i interrupt the program i get this:

```
File "c:/Users/kathy/Documents/Cuarentena/Pruebas de reconocimiento de voz/prueba1.py", line 9, in <module>
    audio = r.listen(source)
  File "C:\Users\kathy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 652, in listen
    buffer = source.stream.read(source.CHUNK)
  File "C:\Users\kathy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 161, in read
    return self.pyaudio_stream.read(size, exception_on_overflow=False)
  File "C:\Users\kathy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 608, in read
    return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames, exception_on_overflow)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Are you sure your microphone index is correct? Have you run the code from the README to determine what the index is?

Comment: Yes, I checked, I only have a microphone and that is its index, and even without that parameter I do not get results

Comment: Read up on [speech_recognition#pyaudio-for-microphone-users](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition#pyaudio-for-microphone-users) and verify if anything are related to your setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing some tests with the same library a long time ago, and I tried two computers, in the newer one I had problems because the sound card automatically filtered the ambient sound and only recognized the last words. While in the other it seemed that it did nothing or took a long time to process the recognition. In the end I did it by adding this line:

```
r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
```

According to the documentation in [SpeechRecognition 3.8.1](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/):

> is probably set to a value that is too high to start off with, and then being adjusted lower automatically by dynamic energy threshold adjustment. Before it is at a good level, the energy threshold is so high that speech is just considered ambient noise.
>
> The solution is to decrease this threshold, or call recognizer_instance.adjust_for_ambient_noise beforehand, which will set the threshold to a good value automatically.

Here's an example:
[speech_recognition/examples/calibrate_energy_threshold.py](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/examples/calibrate_energy_threshold.py)

Comment: Great, thank you very much, I followed the example, and now it works.